# Apply searching creteria to subform .Filter property from another form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

Basically, I have a form `MENU` that has a subform, `Tabella1`.
What I want to do is a searching query that operates on 4 different fields of `Tabella1`.

The query actually works, but instead of updating the subform inside `MENU`, it opens a new datasheet with the result of the search.

**EDIT**
Ok so now I followed @June7 advice, in particular I used [this guide](http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html) and basically I deleted the previous query.
The problem now is that, it all works fine, except that after executing `cmdFiltra_Click()` *-for the button CERCA-*, it simply shows nothing.
Plus, if I use the date criteria, instead of the other 4 criterias, it shows all records, although at the bottom of the form the message "Filtered" appears.

This is the re-adapted code *-for my situation-* of the form `Cerca`:

```
Private Sub cmdFiltra_Click()

Dim strWhere As String                  
Dim lngLen As Long                      
Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"   

If Not IsNull(Me.regioneRicerca) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Forms]![MENU]![Tabella1].[Form].[REGIONE SOCIALE] Like ""*" & Me.regioneRicerca & "*"") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.localitaRicerca) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Forms]![MENU]![Tabella1].[Form].[LOCALITA] Like ""*" & Me.localitaRicerca & "*"") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.fiscaleRicerca) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Forms]![MENU]![Tabella1].[Form].[CODICE FISCALE] Like ""*" & Me.fiscaleRicerca & "*"") AND "
End If


If Not IsNull(Me.stallaRicerca) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Forms]![MENU]![Tabella1].[Form].[CODICE STALLA] Like ""*" & Me.stallaRicerca & "*"") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtStartDate) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Forms]![MENU]![Tabella1].[Form].[EnteredOn] >= " & Format(Me.txtStartDate, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If


If Not IsNull(Me.txtEndDate) Then  
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Forms]![MENU]![Tabella1].[Form].[EnteredOn] < " & Format(Me.txtEndDate + 1, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If

lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then    
    MsgBox "Inserisci almeno un criterio.", vbInformation, "Nessun criterio inserito"
Else                    
    strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)

    Forms!MENU!Tabella1.Form.Filter = strWhere
    Forms!MENU!Tabella1.Form.FilterOn = True
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdReset_Click()

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.Section(acDetail).Controls
    Select Case ctl.ControlType
    Case acTextBox, acComboBox
        ctl.Value = Null
    Case acCheckBox
        ctl.Value = False
    End Select
Next

Forms!MENU!Tabella1.Form.FilterOn = False

End Sub
```

Tell me if you need any other information, sorry in advance if I wasn't clear enough.

**Screenshots**

Form MENU before:
[image: form MENU before]

Form MENU after:  [image: form MENU after]

Comment: So why is a datasheet opening? Show the rest of the code. Query statement alone does not cause a sheet to open. Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: @June7 thanks for the help, it was very useful! Now I just updated my question. I have still a problem unfortunately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
My error was in referring the Form `fields`. For example, I changed `[Forms]![MENU]![Tabella1].[Form].[REGIONE SOCIALE]` to just `[REGIONE SOCIALE]`, and `[Forms]![MENU]![Tabella1].[Form].[EnteredOn]` to `[INSERITO IL]`, and so on.
Thanks to @June7 anyway for the precious guide!